# Error in preview a container in tagmanager in android

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I integrated the tagmanager in android for adwords conversion tracking. I want to test the container in preview mode. So I did all the things described on the google's developer page [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/).

I included the complete code needed for preview the container. But when I tried to launch the app from QR scanner or the link provided by tagmanager for preview.

It says:

sorry we cannot open this link. there is not any apps installed which can handle it.

Is anything I have to do except the above mentioned things.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon similar problem. Solved by correctly reading the manual. Steps I did:

Add this to your android manifest file and replace your information:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.PreviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">  <!-- optional, removes the previewActivity from the activity stack. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="YOUR WHOLE APP PACKAGE NAME" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

then go to GTM administration website -> container versions -> your current version -> actions -> preview and enter your WHOLE package name into the box. "eg. com.example.mygtm"

then proceed to open the link, copy adb command or scan QR code.

Hope this helps !